# Prevent mouse click on parent absolute element

Tags: javascript, css

I am having problem with two absolute elements in css like this

```html
<div class="opacity" (click)="hideContext()">
    <div class="context-menu-wrapper">
        <div class="list-group">
            <span (click)="goThere()" class=" list-group-item pl-25 pr-29">
                <i class="icon-pencil "></i>1
            </span>
            <span (click)="goThere()" class=" list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-pencil "></i>2
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css for two elements

```css
.opacity {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 999999;
}

.context-menu-wrapper{
    max-width:250px; 
    min-width: 250px; 
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

**When I click on A it always call function hideContext(), becasue parent is absolute and child is absolute**

Comment: The problem is not clear enough. Do you want to disable click on parent element or, is it that, you want to prevent the function call bind with parent, when you click on child element,.

Comment: I need to prevent function call bind with parent

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

**HTML :** Used `onclick` attribute for calling function.

**CSS :** Removed `pointer-events: none;` from `.context-menu-wrapper`.

**JavaScript :** Added `event.stopPropagation()` in `goThere()` so that, the click does not call the click event bind with any ancestor element.

```js
function hideContext(event) {
  alert("hideContext()");
}

function goThere() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("goThere()");
}
```

```css
.opacity {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 999;
}

.context-menu-wrapper {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}

span {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="opacity" onclick="hideContext(event)">
  <div class="context-menu-wrapper">
    <div class="list-group">
      <span onclick="goThere()" class=" list-group-item pl-25 pr-29">
                <i class="icon-pencil "></i>1
            </span>
      <span onclick="goThere()" class=" list-group-item">
                <i class="icon-pencil "></i>2
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```